# Android Studio Emulator: Setting cellular signal strength to "none" still allows network traffic to go through

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to simulate poor network connectivity.

I set Android Studio's emulator Cellular to Signal strength = None, but it is still allowing network traffic to go through (I am making successful HTTP requests using Okhttp after setting "None" in the emulator)

Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: I submitted this as a bug to Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116536183

Comment: I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue in latest (current) build as well. I added comment to issue tracker with Google, but it doesn't look like this bug is getting any attention.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it's a bug. That seems to be a non-functional UI button jammed into the emulator, just to be made functional someday. Changing settings to any given option takes no effect

Comment: Jan 2024 here and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug - I also stumbled upon the problem and found this bug-report:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136937549
Interestingly switching to roaming there switches off the network for me (what I mainly needed - maybe it helps you too)
Otherwise staring the issue can help getting a fix sooner as google then knows it is annoying to devs.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set 'Network type'.
I think this is a bug... so confused about it.I mean 'how Cellular data works without signal strength???'

Comment: Try GPRS or EDGE, LTE means full speed.

Comment: I tried changing the network type, it doesn't make a difference